# How do I combine Excel pivot table Rows?

Tags: excel, excel-pivot

Say I have a basic table of data with 1 question asked twice (once before, once after to compare responses).

| Question 1: Before | Question 1: After |
| --- | --- |
| WRONG | CORRECT |
| CORRECT | CORRECT |
| WRONG | CORRECT |

I do a pivot table on this data and i get:

[image]

[image]

However, I want to combine the Rows, so it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Load your source table to Power Query, highlight both columns and then use the Unpivot Columns feature within the Transform ribbon. You can then create your desired Pivot Table from this new table quite easily.

Comment: The ooutput you want is not possible using only Pivot Tables. You need to use PowerQuery or manually construct your headers and first column and then use COUNTIFS to get desired output